# Recovering Hard Drive Files from Git Clone Over Local Project

Tags: git, file, recovery

I had a local project directory (with lots of work) in my hard drive that wasn't associated with git. Trying to set it up with Git, I created an empty repo on GitLab and cloned it onto my machine.

The issue is that I cloned it one directory above where my local project directory was located, overwriting all my previous work. The only files in there now are .git and README.md. What, if anything, can I do to get my local project files back?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO!
You can try it with [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva)
Recuva is a data recovery tool, actually it's one of the best.

**Important: Do not use the hard drive now, if you do so you could override the lost files!**

Comment: @– JacobSloan: Hi, if that helped you, you can upvote the answer and give it an accepted mark. This is the way of showing appreciation on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Yes I'm trying but my SO reputation isn't high enough yet. Maybe one day!